# 'mat-select' is not a known element when making build in angular 5

Tags: angular-material, angular5, production-environment

I am using lazy loading in my Angular 5 project and I have a shared module in which all the material components are imported and I use this shared module in my other module for material modules.

All components are working fine in development mode but when I make build for production it shows error that `'mat-select'` is not a known element without showing any line number.

I have imported shared module in my components that are using angular material and also in my `app.component.ts` file. I searched everywhere but no luck.

Answer (score 14):

For newer versions of Angular (I'm on Angular 11):

```
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
```

see [MatSelectModule API](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) for more information.

Answer (score 13):

Add below in your respective module.

```
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and `MatSelectModule` in imports.